# Expression tree ToString with format/culture

Tags: c#, linq, expression, expression-trees

So here is the basic of what i want to achieve:

```
string.Format(new CultureInfo("da-DK"), "{0:n}", myDouble)
```

(Formatting a number with a culture. Example input: 1, output: "1,00")

Context: I need to achieve this with an expression tree, my current code produces a search query, going through product prices, in which it should format doubles.
Here is what i've got so far:

```
 var query = context.Products;
 var searchquery = "1,00" //example
 var propertyName = "Price"; //example
 var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ProductClass), "type");
 var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, propertyName);
 MethodCallExpression propertyExpToStringToLower; //value initialized depending on type.
 if (propertyExp.Type == typeof(double))
 {
 // Example value: 1, needed value: "1,00".                                              
 // Here I want to change the double to the correct format, ToString.
 }
 else
 {
 //ToString's and ToLower's other attributes (string, int, where no format is needed)
 propertyExpToStringToLower = Expression.Call(Expression.Call(propertyExp, propertyExp.Type.GetMethod("ToString", System.Type.EmptyTypes)), typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", System.Type.EmptyTypes));
 }
 MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
 var seachValue = Expression.Constant(searchquery.ToLower(), typeof(string));
 var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyExpToStringToLower, method, seachValue);

Expression<Func<ProductClass, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<ProductClass, bool>>
         (containsMethodExp, parameterExp);

query = query.Where(predicate);
```

As a quick side note, I am not very experienced with expression trees but the code is working with a string attribute like ProductName, Just not with numbers. I image I can call ToString with a format? But I have not been able to find any examples.

**Question:** How do I format an expression value with a format/culture?

Comment: Will your expression tree represent database query? For example you are going to use it with Entity Framework?

Comment: @Evk yes!
Does that change the question/answer?

Comment: @Evk OP is using `MethodCallExpression`, which has issue to work with any remote system / database, it's best utilized for in memory processing, method definition / schema is available, since cannot be serialized across the network call

Comment: You can simply create an Overload / Extension method and use `MethodCallExpression` to achieve the expected result

Comment: You might want to keep server unaware of client locale as server might not know the specific culture's rules. You get your culture-invariant data from server to local list or array and then iterate over it to have data formatted the way you need. This will also keep your code much cleaner.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I am using MethodCallExpressions because they are the only way I know of to create a reflective query in linq. I.e a query that can search for Price."Name" == "Shoe". does this make sense?

Can you give me an example or a link of any kind to a overload where the value is changed?

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov Yes, that is correct, it would be better for me to first pull out the data and then format it, then iterate it. But this way it takes to much time, It is way quicker to query the database to receive a smaller amout of data rather than formatting my over 10k elements first. The culture currently always has to be DKK.

Comment: It changes answer, because Entity Framework will not be able to translate your `ToString(new CultureInfo("da-DK"))` to SQL query.

Comment: @Patrick My point is different, you need `MethodCallExpression` since your requirement is custom / you need data transformation, if there's a `String` overload, then use it directly or else you need an extension method for string type. For entity framework this may work, but `MethodCallExpression` across process boundary has challenges and mostly it doesn't work.

Comment: @Patrick you can do formatting on every object received using regular *foreach*, and it might be even quicker to format on calling side as less data to be received from unmanaged code. `foreach (var rec in query) {result.Add(new Class{Field=rec.Decimal.ToString(culture)});}`

Comment: @Evk yes, that is why i Currently transform doubles in the GUI. The only problem that I have is if users search for certain numbers, the query does not know the GUI transformation, which is why I am trying to let the search query know the format.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj, 2 questions, #1: Well ToString(IFormatProvider) will also do the trick, but I don't know how to use it with MethodCallExpression. #2: What do you mean with "MethdCallExpression" accross process boundary has challanges"? It is working fine when searching for Ints, strings, just not doubles with diffrent format.

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov Yes, currently I am doing formatting in the GUI intead of db, because it is way cheaper to format the 100 products that I am showing than formatting the 10k products in the database. Currently my query takes around ½ secound, where as it takes 15+ if i first format and array 10k products. 
The only problem I have is with user search queries, which all work, except for ones with doubles.

Comment: @Patrick did you try to throw off this formatting stuff to a background `Task` and `await` in UI thread for the result?

Comment: Your current approach (trying to get `ToString(CultureInfo)` in expression tree) will not work as described above. Best way would be to format your parameter according to database culture and not visa versa. For example, `if (double.TryParse(searchQuery, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, deCulture, out result)) { ... convert it to your database culture ...}`

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov no, I am not a fan of Task await. 
Do you mean that I should turn my 15 secound data formatting query into a Task?

Comment: @Patrick not only formatting but all non-UI things, database interaction included. If you need user to wait until the operation completes, use some kind of BusyIndicator.

Comment: @Evk I think I understand what you mean, I should turn "1,00" into 1, so that it matches the 1 from my database? and not the other way around. 
"1,30" becomes 1,3. I didn't think of that! wow, thanks!

Comment: @Patrick ignore the point related to process boundaries, if its working for you. Using expression tree you are working with `IQueryable` type, which needs to be translated into relevant query of the remote system like database / Cache, where most of the systems are incompatible with something like `MethodCallExpression`, they would though support `BinaryExpression`, but not the custom methods, even calling the default methods like `ToString` or `Contains`, which you are doing

Comment: Actually you shall make it 1.00, being double, that would be match, if its decimal type not integer in the database

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov Ahh okay, makes sense, but does making them to Tasks save me any time? anyways, I think I have the answer (credit to Evk)

Comment: @Patrick, does this translates into the query that you want to call, `ToString` on a `double` type

`double d = 1.0;`
 `d.ToString("{0:n}",new CultureInfo("da-DK"))`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Ahh okay, I understand. Ohh well, it works for me, I'll keep it in mind though! but credit to Evk i have an answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not worth trying to build expression tree for `string.Format(new CultureInfo("da-DK"), "{0:n}", myDouble)` (or `ToString(new CultureInfo("da-DK"))`) calls, because you are using this expression tree with Entity Framework, and it will not be able to translate such statement to SQL query.

Instead of trying to convert database values to desired culture - convert your input to the culture database expects:

```
var searchquery = "1,00"; //example
var expectedCulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
var targetCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US"); // for example
double searchValue;
if (double.TryParse(searchquery, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, targetCulture, out searchValue)) {
    searchquery = searchValue.ToString(targetCulture);
}
```

If you will go this route - you might notice that there might actually be no need to convert number back to string, because since you now know it's a number - you can compare it with equals and not `ToString().Contains(...)` like you are doing now. `ToString().Contains(...)` will produce quite bad SQL query, which will be forced to evaluate every row in the table. If you will compare price directly (that is, like: `c => c.Price == doubleValue`) - you will be able to use database index on that column (if any), and even without index I'd expect it to execute faster. But note that such comparision is not exactly the same as `Contains(...)`. For example if user types "1.00" - contains will return prices like "111.00", "231.00" and so on, while equality comparision will return just exact matches. Whether it is desirable to use `Contains` or not when searching for prices - only you can decide.

Side note: using `double` when working with prices is a bad idea. Use `decimal` instead.